# How to render Libgdx model with 32k+ verticies

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I'm loading into Libgdx a *.obj file that contains vertices count more than Java `short`. As result indices are not used and `meshpartsize` is 0. So `modelBatch.render(instances, environment);` has no effect and model isn't rendered.

How can I solve this?